# Passive View Pattern: Communication Among Components

Tags: design-patterns, mvp

I treat each MVP triad as a isolated component. With the View implements a IView interface for example, the Presenter only know the View thru IView of course.

That what I can make the component as reusable as possible.
Now I have to combine those MVP components to form an application. I am wondering what the good practice is to keep those components as separated as possible. But of course I would need to have them communicate/react to each other.

Can I just make the IView exposed to the other's Presenters? Or should I just let the presenters communicate with each other without knowing about the underlying Views?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVP I see the presenters as the orchestrators of activity. As such they are the natural choice on which to base the composition of an application.

Exposing the view of a presenter to other presenters breaks the idea of encapsulation within the MVP pattern. While it doesn't reduce the reusability of the component exposing its view, it does reduce the reusability of a component making use of another component's view as it increases that components dependencies.

So I would keep the views private to the presenters and only let the presenters communicate with each other.

---

**Elaboration** in response to comment

When I say keep the view private to the presenter, I mean private: not exposed to the outside world except through the mediation of the presenter. Of course the presenter can expose methods to the outside world which will cause it to manipulate its view. If the presenter does this through an interface, it may actually use its own view as a delegate for the interface implementation, but - contrary to what you are proposing - the presenter delegates stuff to the view and not the other way around.

Doing it this way ensures, or at least makes it a lot more likely that all interaction logic stays within the presenters and does not get littered throughout presenters and views.

A view should only be manipulated by its presenter. Now of course you can reuse views in multiple presenters, but the instance of a view should only be manipulated by the presenter that instantiated it. If you expose it directly (even through whole or part interfaces), you start having to deal with a view that can be manipulated by mulitple presenters and no single presenter is in control of the view anymore.

The only code I have in the view are the notifications to its presenter of what a user has done (also known as user gestures in some MVP discussions). It is up to the presenter to decide what to do about it. I also keep all logic about which controls to enable/disable in response to user selections in the presenter and not in the view. That not only keeps all interaction logic in the presenter, but also helps towards creating unit-testable user-interfaces (forms).

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this? I would assume you mean exposing the presenter thru an interface. This interface should only contain methods/events relevant for outside interaction with the View. With this can I just split the IView interface implemented by the View into 2 parts: one is private use for its presenter, and the other is for the presenter expose to the outside. Now the Presenter can implement the same public interface and be a delegate for its View. Or it can just return the View thru that split interface.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a good practice to orchestrate the presenters is to use an event bus.
presenters register to the bus and listen to events, that they need to react to.
other presenters throw events on the bus to let possible targets know, what
they just did.
The messages should be based on the problem domain, not technical 
(e.g. "product 123 created")

a [good example](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) is the gwt mvp architecture
and [the newer version](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces).